# Using strcpy() in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

This is not a duplicate as you might think in first look.

The `strcpy()` deprecation in Visual Studio is already known for a few years, as a difficulty when you try to port your C code from GCC to MSVC.

In Visual Studio 2013, all the workarounds of defining `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` fail to solve the issue - the compilation is still failing on this error (It is called "warning", but it is actually an error that causes the compilation to fail).

My question is whether there is an elegant way to solve it within the code?

For example, such a macro would help me a lot:

```
#ifdef SOMETHING_THAT_INDICATES_ITS_MSVC_COMPILER
    Some macro that makes the following substitution:
        strcpy(dest, src) -> strcpy_s(dest, strlen(src), src)
#endif
```

Could you please tell me:

- If you think it is a good approach to solve this portability issue?
- How to correctly write such a macro?
- Any other recommendations?

Comment: Define `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` and go.

Comment: I wrote here that it does not work in VS2013. DId you try it?

Comment: `strlen(src)` should be `strlen(src)+1`

Comment: `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` works fine for me in VS2013. Make sure you define it in your precompiled header or in your project settings under `C/C++::Preprocessor`.

Comment: Put it in project preprocessor definitions - then it works. It is true that simple `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`  does not work...(?!)

Comment: Put in `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` as said earlier, or put it in stdafx.h and rebuild. Ignore Microsoft's recommendations.

Comment: [Everyone please read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486938/c4996-function-unsafe-warning-for-strcpy-but-not-for-memcpy/23490019#23490019) before making any unintelligent Microsoft comments about strcpy being unsafe.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani You should post that as the correct answer, it would be very helpful as this question seems to pop up somewhat frequently.

Comment: Actually someone posted an answer like that in the post I linked so I'm guessing this is a duplicate after all. @SomethingSomething if you don't get it working by modifying stdafx please drop a comment here and I'll re-open. Nothing wrong with the question after all, it's a good one.

Comment: I don't want the `stdafx.h` solution. I don't expect all my library users to start patching their compiler just for my lib

Comment: @uesp - doesn't work when you define it in the first line of all the headers in the project. I think I'll finally implement my own `strcpy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro that you suggested uses `strcpy_s` in an unsafe way, i.e. as if it were a `strcpy`. The reason the use is unsafe is that the second parameter is meant to represent the length of the destination, not the length of the source. If the source is long enough to cause memory overrun, `strcpy_s` is not going to help.

Your approach could work as a way to silence the compiler, but the deprecation is there for a reason: `strcpy` is unsafe, so you should make an effort to use `strcpy_s` instead.

Going at it from the other end would be better: instead of defining a macro that dresses `strcpy` as `strcpy_s` on MSVC, define a macro in gcc to dress up `strcpy_s` as `strcpy` to maintain portability.

To achieve this, go through your source code, and replace all uses of `strcpy` with `strcpy_s`, passing the size of the destination as the second parameter. Then conditionally define a macro that converts `strcpy_s` to `strcpy` by dropping the middle parameter on gcc, write your own `strcpy_s` or [borrow someone else's implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067728/335858) on gcc.

Comment: What will happen in MSVC? It will fail on multiple definition of `strcpy_s()`. I think I'll implement `my_strcpy()` for both platforms...

Comment: @SomethingSomething You should not define your own `strcpy_s` on MSVC, only on gcc. Use conditional compile for that.

Comment: How can I indicate that it is MSVC? is there some `#ifdef SOMETHING_THAT_INDICATES_MSVC` ?

Comment: @SomethingSomething `_WIN32` is a common one. Here is a [Q&A about that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/904762/335858).

Comment: @SomethingSomething I suggest `_MSC_VER` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If src is not properly terminated, this will crash, also if dst is too short for src - which is the reason to use `strcpy_s()` actually. You have to take the shortest size of source (`- 1`) and destination. However, as these mostly come from pointers, the length information is not available anymore.

A **proper** (and portable) solution would be to fix the affected code to use `strcpy_s()` properly. A **hackish** solution *might* be to simply pass a length value to `strcpy_s()` larger than any string might have, e.g. `RSIZE_MAX`, which is the max. allowed length. That would be no more or less secure than `strcpy()` or your approach. **Disclaimer: I strongly discourage from doing so! Get the code right instead!**.